# Graph Control in Java/Netbeans? Does it exist?

Tags: java, netbeans, controls, graph

Is it possible that anyone has a link to a graph class/library that I can use to produce a graph in Java?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Mathematical graph or visual graph?

Answer (score 4):

My top choice would be JGraph as others have suggested; I am using [JGraph5](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph5.html) because it is better documented than the newer alternative, [JGraphX](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraphx.html).  EDIT: JGraphX turns out to be the far superior version, despite the lack of documentation.  It's not *that* hard to figure out.

### JGraph

- [Demonstration app](http://www.mxgraph.com/demo/jgraphx/jgraphx.jnlp)
- [Feature list](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraphfeatures.html)
- [Licensing agreement](http://www.jgraph.com/license.html)

Other alternatives I've researched:

### JGraphT

"JGraphT is a free Java graph library that provides mathematical graph-theory objects and algorithms...complete source code included, under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License." (http://jgrapht.sourceforge.net/)

- [Main project repository](http://jgrapht.sourceforge.net/)
- [Example visualizations](http://jgrapht.sourceforge.net/visualizations.html)

### JUNG - Java Universal Network/Graph Framework

[Main project repository](http://jung.sourceforge.net/)

### yEd Graph Editor

- Implementation of [yFiles library](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfiles_practicalinfo_gallery.html)
- [Demonstration Java applet](http://www.yworks.com/products/yed/demo/yed.jnlp)
- [About yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html)
- Saves graphs in [GraphML](http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/) format

Comment: This is contingent on you actually meaning Graph as in mathematical graph; if you mean charts, then like the others suggest, JFreeChart is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

I used [JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/) as a visualizer for networks of nodes/topologies at my previous job, it's not half bad once you get past the architecture (it's a big state machine if I recall correctly).

Answer (score 1):

Visual graph: [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/)

You may also wish to consider the [Google Charts API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/), if you can make web service requests.

Answer (score 1):

A really good alternative is to used the [Google Charts API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/). Platform independent, easy to use, and fast processing (done on Google Server side)

Answer (score 0):

[graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) would be my choice.  It's not Java, but still terrific and easy to use.

There is a [Java component](http://www.vclcomponents.com/Java/Scripts_and_Programs/Miscellaneous/GraphViz_Java_API-info.html) that works with dot to generate graphs.  I've used it - very nice, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend JGraphT. I used it to create multi-leveled graphs in my dissertation and as the base of a GPS Routing Software, understanding what is going on I found a bit of a mind bender, but once looking at how the algorithms package works I found it quite easy to implement A*/D* heuristic algorithms. For working out the distance between nodes on the graph I'd also recommend looking at the Haversine function, if that's your thing.