# A WireIt like GUI library for Netbeans/Swing

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, yahoo-pipes

I am looking for an open-source java library for creating yahoo-pipes like GUI. [Wireit](http://javascript.neyric.com/wireit/) is based on javascript. Prefer LGPL/Apache License that can be used for commercial purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for a generic Java graph library, perhaps [JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html) would be an option.

Answer (score 1):

I agree JGraph is a good option; see my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704069/graph-control-in-java-netbeans-does-it-exist/1704822#1704822) for other alternatives.

JGraphX is actually MUCH superior to JGraph 5, so do not be fooled into using it for the better documentation.  It's not worth it.